# Wakeup Watch app OS2 from the parent IOS app?

Tags: watchos-2

I would like to give a haptic feedback on the watch. That works fine as long as the watch app is active, but if the watch app goes in background the haptic feedback is not played. Is there a possibility to "wake up" the watch app from the parent IOS app to play the haptic feedback? (NOT A NOTIFICATION)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you prohibit Notifications, is not possible to do what you describe.  Your watch app can act on messages from the iOS only when it starts up, resumes, or is currently loaded and running.

WatchConnectivity gives you 5 ways of sending data between the watch and phone.

sendMessage, sendMessageData: your scenario excludes these calls since both the watch and iPhone apps need to be active for this mechanism to work.

updateApplicationContext, transferUserData, and transferFile can be invoked from the iOS app at anytime, regardless of the state of your watch app.  However, these messages are sent on a background thread and your watch app delegate will receive them the next time the watch app is loaded.  By the design of the watch OS, none of these methods can trigger the watch app to load or become active.